# how to run emacsclient on windows in the terminal

Tags: microsoft-windows, emacsclient

i cannot use emacsclient on windows 10.
Starting it with the gui client works well but trying to start it in command line mode from a terminal, for example running
emacsclient -nw -c
is there a correct way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

On Windows there is no **terminal** version of Emacs, only Gui-versions. So using `emacslient.exe` or `emacsclientw.exe` is the same thing. The behave slightly different in what they tell you on the command line. `emacsclient.exe` starts a CMD console if run from Start menu or explorer. `emacsclientw.exe` is a native GUI application that starts as any Windows app.

But you can still start a daemon with multiple client windows. The first client needs to start a server if there is no running already. You do that by adding `-a ""` as an option. This tells Emacs to connect to the default server named "". You can start multiple servers with different names if needed. And you need to add `-c` to create a new frame, otherwise emacsclient reuse an existing frame. And that is useful if you want to open a file from the command line.

You can add the option `--tty` to emacsclient but that don't make any difference. You will get a GUI window anyway.

```
emacsclient.exe -c -a ""

- or-

emacsclientw.exe -c -a ""

- or -

emacsclient.exe --tty -c -a ""
```

All above will start a server and a window.

Or you can start the server first, either in background or foreground, and then start the emacsclient. Running a foreground server is good for troubleshooting. And the background is probably wanted when in a stable state.

```
emacs.exe --fg-daemon

- or -

emacs.exe --bg-daemon


emacsclient.exe -c

emacsclientw.exe -c
```

So the short answer, `emacsclientw.exe -c -a ""` should be the command you are looking for.

To start a new client, use `C-x 5 2`, and to close the window, `C-x 5 0`. And to exit Emacs, run `M-x kill-emacs` to kill all windows and the server.

Hopes this helps.

Comment: So I was wrong about that there being no *terminal* version of Emacs on Windows. To my surprise there was if you start with `emacs.exe -nw`. I guess that I used emacsclient.exe for so long and when that stop working I gave up on that. And forgot about it.

Comment: But it won't help anyway since you can't run an emacsclient in another console than in that the server is running. Described in the documentation, last paragraph.
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Windows-Startup.html

So strictly speaking you can run emacsclient in a terminal, but it's not practical in reality.

Emacsclient and server don't support the '-s' option, a named server, so there is likely no way to make this work. Could be wrong, but my tests didn't work as they did with the GUI version.